# Where to place images in assetic when references from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, assetic

I am using assetic in Symfony 2.  I have JavaScript and CSS loaded using assetic.

I need to reference some images in one of my JS files.  I am new to assetic, and cannot find any documentation on this at all.  The images currently reside in my bundle (`/src/Vendor/BundleName/Resources/img/chair.jpg` for example).

I see one major pitfall here:
How would assetic have any idea what the image path is?  As far as it's concerned it's just a string in a JS file.  So, do I need to define that image path somewhere else or do I reference it in a different way within the JavaScript?

Or am I to not use assetic at all and just throw my images into the public directory (`web` by default)?  I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should then use [JmikolaJsAssetsHelperBundle](https://github.com/jmikola/JmikolaJsAssetsHelperBundle).

which allows you to expose the `AssetsHelper` service from Symfony2's templating component to JavaScript.

It supports both relative and absolute asset URI(s).

**Example,**

Once configured, the bundle creates a `AssetsHelper` global variable within your javascript. It allows you then to call a `getUrl()` helper to build your asset path as follow,

```
'<img src="' + AssetsHelper.getUrl('/images/yourImage.png') + '">';
```

Comment: And I can use this within .js files?

Comment: Yes. It's the main purpose of this bundle.